# Self-contained modular classes using Microsoft Entity Framework / Linq to SQL

Tags: .net, entity-framework, linq-to-sql

I've been using .NET 2 for web programming for several years (due to the limited support we have for anything else on the servers we're using), but have recently started looking at using .NET 4 for some new projects.

As part of this, I've been trying to learn how to use the Microsoft Entity Framework / Linq to SQL.  It seems that it makes the basics very straightforward and you can put together a fully functioning class in no time at all.  However, now I'm starting to push it a bit further I'm finding issues that I'm not sure how to get around.

One of the things that's bothering me is that I don't understand how to organise things. Obviously I'm used to keeping related classes in namespaces and generally these namespaces reflect the layout of the database (eg. namespaces map to table name prefixes).  Using the EF though, it seems that every one of my classes has to be in the same namespace.  I can of course have several data contexts in seperate namespaces, but then I lose the advantages that the EF offers as the classes no longer have any relationship to one another.  I can live with this, but I feel like I must be missing something?

The other issue I've got which is bothering me even more is that I'm used to building self-contained modular classes and I don't understand how this is possible with EF.  For example, I can't figure out how to write a simple Save function, because if you call db.SaveChanges() then changes to the entire database are saved - and if you're calling mySingleObject.Save() then this doesn't seem like a desirable thing to do as it'd also save changes to any other objects you happen to have been messing around with.  Given that I'm building this functionality in to a class library, having to call db.SaveChanges() from outside the class library also seems crazy, because anything outside my class library shouldn't require any knowledge of how my data is stored.

Am I missing the point of this or do I need to change my way of thinking?

At the moment I'm struggling to advance my project because of these issues, and I'm considering going back to plain old SQL. This would be a shame because the EF clearly has some massive advantages, and I'd like to make the most of it!

Answer (score 1):

I've never run into an issue with having to keep all of my database entities in the same namespace.  I don't think it's obvious that one would create namespaces that are related in anyway to the database.  I think that introduces a tight coupling that's best avoided all together, specifically your application shouldn't care about the schema of the underlying datastore.  I think namespaces are commonly used to group (and scope) logical entities - i.e. all classes relating to logging, or, in this case, all classes related to interacting with a persistence store.

Your other concern seems equally unfounded to me.  Can you provide an example of when you'd want to commit some object state to the store and not others?  EF provides a mechanism for executing transactions, so you are fine on that front.

In general, the [active record pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_record_pattern) of a single class representing a row in the database is falling out of favor and the repository pattern ([previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3175/repository-pattern-tutorial-in-c-sharp), [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649690.aspx)) is taking it's place.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm sure you're right on both points, I think the problem is that I'm too set in my current way of thinking!

Regarding namespaces, say I have a 'Customer' class and a 'Product' class, each relating to a table in the database. Traditionally, I might have put these into a 'User' namespace and an 'Ecommerce' namespace respectively. Given that 'Customer' and 'Product' would now be entities, these would now be forced in to being in the same namespace. Is this right as I'll probably have about 50 entities in the end which will all be in one place?

Comment: Regarding my other point, I'd expect the following to update a single customer: `Customer myCustomer = Customer.Get(1); myCustomer.Name = "Fred"; myCustomer.Save();`, but using EF this will save any other changes which have been made to any other entities too. Again, I obviously need to adjust my way of thinking but I'm just trying to understand how this functionality *should* be written using the EF.